# How do I fix this custom "Backspace" option in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I have this custom Keyboard that I made which basically just consists of A LOT of text animation; Anyway, everything works except for the backspace feature, what I need it to do is turn the last character(%char%) selected into a blank text value. Here's what I got to save the selected text but the backspace feature doesn't seem to do anything.

```
:enter
set nchar=%lchar%%char%
set lchar=%nchar%
goto %place%

:nback
set char=
goto %place%
```

It originally comes from this bit of code, which is just copied and pasted OVER AND OVER with few adjustments for visual pleasure.

```
:A
set char=A
set place=A
cls
echo  DONE  BACK  SPACE  QUIT
echo ________________________
echo  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
echo  9  0 [A] B  C  D  E  F
echo  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N
echo  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V
echo  W  X  Y  Z  a  b  c  d
echo  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l
echo  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t
echo  u  v  w  x  y  z  !  ?
choice /c WASDE /n
if ERRORLEVEL 5 goto enter
if ERRORLEVEL 4 goto B
if ERRORLEVEL 3 goto I
if ERRORLEVEL 2 goto n0
if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto n3
```

Comment: Please add enough of your code to the question that I can copy all of the code you provide and run it without errors. Right now, you'll get an error about `%place%` not existing and `:nback` never gets called. Also, you're going to want to check out the DOSTips page on substrings,
 specifically the [Left](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringOperations.php#Snippets.LeftString) and [TrimRight](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringOperations.php#Snippets.TrimRightFOR) parts..

Comment: I could add all of the code, but it's VERY BIG, let me see what I can do

Comment: I'm going to add a single part that makes up the entire thing

Comment: I'm completely okay with posting my entire code with pastebin or something, just not on here with the 4 required spaces and what not, I'm sure you understand.

Comment: I just need enough of it that it will run properly; it doesn't have to be the entire thing. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Here's the whole code, because honestly you would be able to run it with a partial bit of it, but it's REALLY hard to understand unless you have the full thing. I really don't care if anyone want's to take it and claim it as their own because I just code for fun, I'd find it flattering https://pastebin.com/fNbBYXM5

Answer (score 0):

Read and follow [Variables: extract part of a variable (substring)](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html):

> It is possible to retrieve specific characters from a string variable.
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> %variable:~num_chars_to_skip%
> %variable:~num_chars_to_skip,num_chars_to_keep%
> ```
>
> This can include negative numbers:
>
> ```
> %variable:~num_chars_to_skip, -num_chars_to_keep%
> %variable:~-num_chars_to_skip,num_chars_to_keep%
> %variable:~-num_chars_to_skip,-num_chars_to_keep%
> ```
>
> A negative number will count backwards from the end of the string.

To extract everything **but the last character** from typed text so far, use

```
:nback
if not "%nchar%"=="" set "nchar=%nchar:~0,-1%"
set char=
goto %place%
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below have the custom Backspace option fixed. I also have modified the program "a little bit"... **`;)`**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "line[1]=  DONE  BACK  SPACE QUIT "
set "line[2]=  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 "
set "line[3]=  9  0  A  B  C  D  E  F "
set "line[4]=  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N "
set "line[5]=  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V "
set "line[6]=  W  X  Y  Z  a  b  c  d "
set "line[7]=  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l "
set "line[8]=  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t "
set "line[9]=  u  v  w  x  y  z  ^!  ? "

set /A row=1, col=1, newRow=1, newCol=1
set "input="

:refresh
set "line[%row%]=!line[%row%]:[= !" & set "line[%row%]=!line[%row%]:]= !"
set /A row=newRow, col=newCol
if %row% equ 1 (set /A j=col*6-4, n=j+5) else set /A j=col*3-1, n=j+2
set /A i=j-1, k=n-j-1
set "line[%row%]=!line[%row%]:~0,%i%![!line[%row%]:~%j%,%k%!]!line[%row%]:~%n%!"

cls
echo/
for /L %%i in (1,1,9) do echo !line[%%i]!
echo/
set /P "=>!input!" < NUL

:getKey
choice /c WASDE /n > NUL
goto key-%errorlevel%


:key-1  W=Up
if %row% equ 1 goto getKey
set /A newRow=row-1, newCol=col
if %newRow% equ 1 if %newCol% gtr 4 set "newCol=4"
goto refresh

:key-2  A=Left
if %col% equ 1 goto getKey
set /A newRow=row, newCol=col-1
goto refresh

:key-3  S=Down
if %row% equ 9 goto getKey
set /A newRow=row+1, newCol=col
goto refresh

:key-4  D=Right
if %col% equ 8 goto getKey
if %row% equ 1 if %col% equ 4 goto getKey
set /A newRow=row, newCol=col+1
goto refresh

:key-5  E=Enter
if %row% equ 1 goto command-%col%
set /A j=col*3-1
set "input=!input!!line[%row%]:~%j%,1!"
goto refresh

:command-3  Space
set "input=!input! "
goto refresh

:command-2  Back
if not defined input goto getKey
set "input=!input:~0,-1!"
goto refresh

:command-1  Done
echo/
echo Done, line read:
echo !input!

:command-4  Quit
```